# How do I validate my html form controls using javascript in cakephp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp, popup

I am using a popup and applying form inside it. Now I want my controls to be validated using javascript. But whenever I try to submit my form it does not validate my form fields at all and simply submits the page

My js code is given below :

```
function validateForm()
 {  
    var regex = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
    var uname = document.getElementById('user_name').value;
    if(uname=="")
    {
        alert("You cannot leave the email field empty");
        return false;
    }
    else if(uname.search(regex) == -1)
    {
        alert("Invalid email address format");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
    return true;

 }
```

My HTML div code is given below . I have used div because my popup is loaded from that div only :

```
<div id="logincontent">
<div class="form-box-top">
    <div class="form-box-bottom">
    <?php echo $this->Form->create('User',array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'id'=>'login', 'name'=>'login','onsubmit'=>'return validateForm();'));?>
        <div class="form-box-middle">
            <div class="login-form">
                <div class="re-title3">
                    <a class="pass" onclick="forget();" href="#">forgot password</a>
                </div>
                <div class="input-row">
                    <label>EMAIL</label>                    
                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('username', array('label' => '','class'=>'required','style'=>'margin: -5px 0px 0px 24px;','id'=>'user_name')); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="input-row"> 
                    <label>PASSWORD</label>
                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('password', array('type'=>'password','class'=>'required','label' => '','style'=>'margin: -5px 0px 0px 24px;')); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="button_3">
                <?php echo $this->Form->submit('',array('label' => '','class'=>''));?>
            </div>
            <div class="button_3_1">
            <a style="background: url(<?php echo $this->webroot       ?>/images/registor-bt2.png) no-repeat left top;
float: left;border: 0px;width: 236px;height: 47px;" onclick="register()"; href="#"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="cr"></div>
        </div>
    <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now whenever I submit my form I want my fields to be validated by js function

I have tried lot but dont know it gives malicious results or unpredicted results.

Any suggestion will be entertained and appreciated..

Thanx in advance....

Comment: just dont forget that you still need the PHP validation in the backend. some programmers forget that the JS validation is totally unimportant compared to the PHP one. especially when a user deactivates JS all hell can break loose otherwise.
since you do not want to create redundancy, try to read your backend validation rules and transform then into JS ones in the view. there are some existing plugins and scripts which try to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1):

Install firebug, if you don't use it already.

I would recommend using a [JQuery UI dialog -> modal form & validation](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form)

If you dont want to use it, you may at least want to check out the regular expression code provided on **line 16.**